# Are hyphens required in this case?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, style, hyphens

I am wondering whether I have to use hyphens in this case? I haven't used them before in the text this sentence is included in, but they seem necessary here. or maybe I could just avoid them?

.Furthermore, this master is crucial to enhance her capacity in researching and developing **underground-water-related** projects, which are necessary to assist in meeting the urgent demand of water for zones with scarcity.

.Furthermore, this master is crucial to enhance her capacity in researching and developing **underground water related** projects, which are necessary to assist in meeting the urgent demand of water for zones with scarcity.

Comment: I think I would avoid the question by saying "projects related to underground water".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphenation of adjectives composed of three words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136088/hyphenation-of-adjectives-composed-of-three-words). Note from one of the answers there that the American Psychological Association style guide favours ***hyphenating all words of a multi-word compound adjective***.

Comment: Basically, "all or nothing" is fine (just make your choice and stick with it), but using only a single hyphen as per ***underground water-related projects*** would be incorrect for your context (unless you intended a ***very*** strange meaning! :)

Comment: Another possibility... is "underground water" different than "groundwater" (M-W : water within the earth especially that supplies wells and springs). If it's the same, you could use "groundwater-related projects".

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty your suggestion is a good alternative, thank you.

Comment: @pepo It's rare to have a compound word with three bases (other than nonce-forms). Without further context, I'd consider "underground water-related projects" as a possibility.